# Remainder of URL path to results array after pattern match

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm having difficulties to get my regex to do what I want it to do :(

I want my regex to do the following 2 things:

1. find the ID which is the next URL path section right after the pattern match for either "brand" or "profile"
2. than split the remainder of the URL path parts after the ID into separate items in the matches array, the number of URL path parts after the ID can vary from none to multiple and the trailing slash is not always there

I managed to get the first part working via:

```
    <?php
    $url = 'https://demo.com/show/profile/123/slug/etc/';
    $pattern = '/\/(brand|profile)?\/([\d]+)/';
    preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
```

Which works for all of these test strings:

```
    https://demo.com/show/profile/123
    https://demo.com/show/profile/123/
    https://demo.com/show/profile/123/slug
    https://demo.com/show/profile/123/slug/
    https://demo.com/show/profile/123/slug/etc
    https://demo.com/show/profile/123/slug/etc/
```

But I don't seem to be able to solve the second part, even after searching for a solution for days. My most "successful" attempt till now is:

```
    \/(brand|profile)?\/([\d]+)\/?(.*)?\/?
```

That pattern captures the remainder of the URL path all together including the trailing slash when it's present (btw - I don't want the trailing slash).

I've the code for the first part available on: [phpliveregex.com/p/pMO](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/pMO)

Can someone help me how to extend that with the code for the second part?

Much appreciated!

Comment: What should be the output? Show us.

Comment: Basically I want to get everything in an array which I can use in a further function. So basically like this: `array( 0 => "/profile/123", 1 => "profile", 2 => 123, 3 => "slug", 4 => "etc")` where I now only get to `array( 0 => "/profile/123", 1 => "profile", 2 => 123)` (see also the phpliveregex link I included). So I like to call the ID via $matches[2] and the next URL path element, if it exists, via $matches[3] and so on.

Comment: Try `(?:\/(brand|profile)\/(\d+)|\G(?!\A))\/([^\/\s]+)` See live demo here https://regexr.com/42b76

Comment: @revo, thanks, looks pretty good already but it seems to skip the first 2 scenario's. Btw - I don't get it to work on my localhost, no idea what i'm doing wrong as the example seems to be for pcre / php, right?

I stumbled upon another regex pattern `/(?:[^\/\n]|\/\/)+/gi` which seems to be very promising as it does it all but should start from the match against (brand|profile), see: https://regex101.com/r/yU6vQ7/25

Comment: I missed first two. Please try https://regex101.com/r/D6K3Im/1

Comment: Nice!! I still have issues getting this to work locally. Is this a preg_match or preg_match_all regex? I've tried both already but get errors.

Comment: Create a live demo and let me check.

Comment: Errors are now gone :S Via preg_match_all I get most of the elements but they are pretty scattered in the results array, see: https://3v4l.org/SqQAh
The 2 step rocket as suggested by @shadowsheep below resulted in this working function: https://3v4l.org/ZRWGN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to split this problem in two sub-problems.

I mean.

Could we do a first `preg_match` with this regex

```
(brand|profile)\/(\d+)(.*)
```

Here we have

- In the 1st capturing group the full match.
- In the 2nd capturing group your tag (brand or profile)
- In the 3rd capturing group we have the ID (the number)
- And in the 4th capturing group the URL reminder

Then with the full URL reminder (4th capturing group) we could do a `preg_match_all` with this regex

```
[^\/]+
```

And here you have all the reminder paths.

Comment: @shadowdeep, sure, that won't be too much of an issue in my opinion. I'll try your above suggestion now. I also stumbled upon another promising regex pattern, see: https://regex101.com/r/yU6vQ7/25
That one just needs to get the start match build in.

Comment: The 2 step rocket approach is useful, this will work for me. The working PHP function I wrote can be found here: https://3v4l.org/ZRWGN

Comment: @golabs I’m happy you got your work done! Often I prefer the KISS approach ‘case I find it easier to read and to mantain.  Even if someone could consider it less geek [-;